# How to do line break on MaterialDesignInXaml Snackbar?

Tags: c#, wpf, line-breaks, snackbar, material-design-in-xaml

Im trying to use a Snackbar to display information, but the text i want to display is too long to fit inside the small window horizontally, so the text isn't shown completely:

[image]

An automatic line break would be super ok.

Setting it manually wouldn't work, because it needs to display different messages.

Comment: Currently working at that...you can follow it at https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/1422

Comment: I've set the Height higher, the snackbar gets bigger, but the Text doesnt wrap around. Do i need to update the Toolkit or enable some property?

Comment: I tried to add &#x0a; in, but it didn't insert a new line

Comment: When i insert \n it creates a new line, but the snackbar doesn't get bigger, so it isn't visible @Rafa Gomez

Comment: 2 lines would be ok, but it doesnt even wrap around 2

Comment: Nevermind, i got it wokring

Answer (score 1):

I actually got it working by setting the property FontFamily:

```
FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it working for arbitrary number of lines, just delete MaxHeight setter for ContentPresenter in SnackbarMessage Style:

```
MaxHeight="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpf:Snackbar}}, Path=(wpf:SnackbarMessage.ContentMaxHeight)}"
```